# How to open a program os.system only using python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system

I am programming a gui using tkinter. I use os.system('file extension'). when I click the button on the gui it should open the next program, but it wont because of python 2. I can use terminal and have pythem3 ./mixed_drink, and this works. Can I set up the code to make the program only run in python 3??

```
from tkinter import *
import os

##############
root = Tk()
root.title('GET YO DRANK MAIN ')
root.geometry("800x400")

def  open_mixed_drinks():
   os.system("/home/pi/mixed_drinks.py")
```

Comment: `os.system("python3 /home/pi/mixed_drinks.py")` - or put at the top of the script itself `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to import the mixed_drink python code? At the moment you're trying to run it in another process

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, try `os.system("python3 /home/pi/mixed_drinks.py")`

This way you are passing the .py file to the default installed python3 binary on your system, rather than the global default python which may still be 2.7 on many systems

Comment: i'm glad it worked, pls press accept if you found it helpful